# Is a python dictionary the best data type for associating numerical values with a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, dictionary

Lets say I have four large numpy arrays (the contents of which don't matter for now):

```
array1 = np.array([stuff1])
array2 = np.array([stuff2])
array3 = np.array([stuff3])
array4 = np.array([stuff4])
```

I also have a list in which I store the names of my numpy arrays as strings:

`my_list = ["array1", "array2", array3", "array4"]`

I would like to iterate over the entries in that list (meaning iterate over my different numpy arrays in effect) and calculate certain quantities which are then stored with the name of that array somehow.

For example:

```
keys = ['name', x, y, z]

for entry in my_list:
     entry + 'dict' = dict.fromkeys(keys)
     entry + 'dict'['name'] = entry
     entry + 'dict'[x] = some calculation involving entry
```

I'm assuming that creating a dictionary for each of my four arrays makes the most sense, but I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this. I also realize that I'm reassigning the variable dictionary_name each time, which is not what I want to do obviously. I essentially just want to store certain attributes with a given numpy array, and reference them easily.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I follow what you are trying to accomplish. You can make a list of dictionaries, or a dictionary of dictionaries. Just don't dynamically create variables. Instead of a dict, you may just want a namedtuple or a simple class/dataclass. Can you elaborate more on exactly what you want as an output?

Comment: I think a list of dictionaries is what I'm after. I'm just not sure how to assign then in a loop. In the example above, I don't know how I would create a list where each list entry is something like 'array1_dict', 'array2_dict', etc

Comment: Again, *what exactly is the output you expect*. It's really hard to say anything without understanding that.

Comment: I'm looking for four dictionaries to have been created. In my for loop I was hoping that I would have created a dictionary each time that was (for example) array1dict, array2dict, etc. 

I'm not sure how to use entries in a list as elements of the left hand side of an assignment statement I guess.

Comment: Again, **don't do that**. Don't create dynamic variables, use a container. Like a list or a dict. So outside the loop `result = []` then in the loop, build a dictionary, then append that dictionary to result